# Joomla component installing warining JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, joomla3.0

I'm using latest Joomla version 3.0.1, and trying to install VirtueMart. When I do, I get the warning:

`"JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file"`

I'm using Wamp Server, so maybe the problem is in the server configuration, because all settings are default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtuemart doesn't support Joomla 3.0 yet. The XML file present uses the `<install>` tag in the xml file which was depreciated at the end of Joomla 1.5 (although still worked in 2.5) however this function has now been removed from Joomla 3.0, hence it can't find a function that works. Due to the large amount of changes that are undergoing for components in Joomla 3.0. Legacy views to start with. I advice using Joomla 2.5 as it is much more stable than 3.0.1 anyway!

Note if you really want to go through and edit the xml file needs `<install>` changed to `<extension>` as well as changing the JModel, Controller and View. (due to upcoming changes to the MVC implementation in the platform, JModel, JView, and JController are re-used as the names of the new interfaces.) So for now, use JModelLegacy, JViewLegacy and JControllerLegacy instead.

Comment: I opened this thread, lets see if a workaround exists: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=121182.0